# Cannot assert all elements in a single array with array that has no identifier name

Tags: karate

response:

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    modelId: "301",
    modelName: "x",
    trimId: "301",
    trimName: "up!",
    derivativeName: "xx",
    fuelType: "PETROL",
    tco: {
      price: {
        tco: null,
        retail: 12,
        offer: null,
        subsidy: null,
        residual: null
      },
      milesPerYear: 10000,
      mpg: 51.5,
      fuelCost: 1.1,
      milesPerKW: 0,
      monthsOfOwnership: 48,
      energyCost: 12,
      tax: 42,
      comparable: false
    }
  },
  {
    id: "1239",
    modelId: "301",
    modelName: "up!",
    trimId: "301",
    trimName: "x",
    derivativeName: "xx",
    fuelType: "PETROL",
    tco: {
      price: {
        tco: null,
        retail: 1,
        offer: null,
        subsidy: null,
        residual: null
      },
      milesPerYear: 10000,
      mpg: 53.2,
      fuelCost: 1.1,
      milesPerKW: 0,
      monthsOfOwnership: 48,
      energyCost: 12,
      tax: 4,
      comparable: false
    }
  }
]
```

I'm trying to check when the key `fuelType` = PETROL then key `fuel Cost` must equal 1.1

I have tried the following

```
* def isValid = function(x) { return response[0].fuelType == "PETROL" &&      response[0].tco.fuelCost == 1.1} 
* match each response === '#? isValid(_)'
```

^^ But this just assert ONLY the top level element.

I have tried the following :

```
* def isValid = function(x) { return response[*].fuelType == "PETROL" &&      response[*].tco.fuelCost == 1.1} * match each response === '#? isValid(_)'
* match each response === '#? isValid(_)'
```

^^ But this throws a operand error.

I have about about *260* elements in a single array with no  indentifeier name and I need to assert for ```fuelType == "PETROL" & fuelCost == 1.1 in all the *260* elements

Comment: I tried to be short and concise which obviously did not work.  I have added another, thank you

Comment: great, the whole point of a "simple example" is lost. anyway, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 lines work perfectly:

```
* def isValid = function(x) { return x.fuelType == "PETROL" && x.tco.fuelCost == 1.1 } 
* match each response == '#? isValid(_)'
```

You used a triple-equals which is wrong. Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-each